# How to get balance from the response retutned by AT?

Tags: php, sms-gateway, jison

I am using Africa's Talking sms services; I  have implemented codes to check balance; but now how can I access **balance** value from this `$response` array? This is the result of `var_dump($response)`.

```
  'status' => string 'success' (length=7)
  'data' => 
    object(stdClass)[106]
      public 'UserData' => 
        object(stdClass)[104]
          public 'balance' => string 'TZS 142.2679' (length=12)
```

Comment: `$response['data']->UserData->balance`

Comment: Wow thats serious :)